# keyboard long press for special characters

Tags: keyboard, special-characters

Is there a way (in KDE) to get the long-press show special characters as in MacOS? I haven't used a Mac in nearly two years and I miss the feature when long pressing the "a" key, for instance, you'd be shown all forms of character "a" with different accentuation marks such as  a-acute, a-tilde, a-grave, a-umlaut, etc.